# How to find the number of binary numbers with the following constraints:

Tags: math, binary, combinatorics

Given a binary digit count of n, and a maximum consecutive occurrence count of m, find the number of different possible binary numbers. Also, the leftmost and rightmost bit must be 1.

For example n = 5, and m = 3.

The count is 7:
10001
10011
10101
10111
11001
11011
11101

Notice we excluded 11111 because too many consecutive 1's exist in it.

This was an interview question I had recently, and It has been bothering me. I don't want to brute force check each number for legitimacy because n can be > 32.

Comment: I think you might have m and n mixed up in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call a binary sequence *almost valid* if it starts with "1" and has at most `m` consecutive "1" digits.

For `i = 1, ..., n` and `j = 0, ..., m` let `a(i, j)` be the number of almost valid sequences with length `i` that end with exactly `j` consecutive "1" digits.

Then

- `a(1, 1) = 1` and `a(1, j) = 0 for j != 1`, because "1" is the only almost valid sequence of length one.
- For `n >= 2` and `j = 0` we have `a(i, 0) = a(i-1, 0) + a(i-1, 1) + ... + a(i-1, m)`, because appending "0" to any almost valid sequence of length `i-1` gives an almost valid sequence of length `i` ending with "0".
- For `n >= 2` and `j > 0` we have `a(i, j) = a(i-1, j-1)` because appending "1" to an almost valid sequence with `i-1` trailing ones gives an almost valid sequence of length `j` with `i` trailing ones.

Finally, the wanted number is the number of almost valid sequences with length `n` that have a trailing "1", so this is

```
f(n, m) = a(n, 1) + a(n, 2) + ... + a(n, m)
```

Written as a C function:

```
int a[NMAX+1][MMAX+1];
int f(int n, int m)
{
    int i, j, s;

    // compute a(1, j):
    for (j = 0; j <= m; j++)
        a[1][j] = (j == 1);

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        // compute a(i, 0):
        s = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= m; j++)
            s += a[i-1][j];
        a[i][0] = s;

        // compute a(i, j):
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            a[i][j] = a[i-1][j-1];
    }

    // final result:
    s = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        s += a[n][j];
    return s;
}
```

The storage requirement could even be improved, because only the last column of the matrix `a` is needed. The runtime complexity is `O(n*m)`.

Answer (score 2):

Without too much combinatorial insight you can tackle this with DP. Let's call <sup>left</sup>#<sub>n,m</sub><sup>right</sup> the number of binary strings of length n, with no substring of consecutive 1's longer than m, beginning with the string left, and ending with the string right. Clearly, we want to find <sup>1</sup>#<sub>n-2,m</sub><sup>1</sup>.

The key observation is simply that <sup>left</sup>#<sub>n,m</sub><sup>right</sup> = <sup>left+'1'</sup>#<sub>n-1,m</sub><sup>right</sup> + <sup>left+'0'</sup>#<sub>n-1,m</sub><sup>right</sup>

A simplistic implementation in js (not sure if it works for small m, and in general untested):

```
function hash(n,m) {

   return _('1',n-2);

   function _(left,n){
      if (m+1 <= left.length && left.lastIndexOf('0') <= left.length-m-2)
         return 0;
      if (n==0)
         return (m <= left.length &&
                 left.lastIndexOf('0') <= left.length-m-1 ? 0:1);
      return _(left+'1',n-1) + _(left+'0',n-1);
   }

}

hash(5,3); // 7
```

Of course this is more efficient than brute force, however the runtime complexity is still exponential, so it isn't practical for large values of n.